# DB2 JSON for windows

Tags: json, db2, db2-luw

I need to enable DB2 Json in my DB2. My current version of DB2 is V9.5. In the internet i came across that the DB2 version should be 10.5 and above. Is is possible to enable it in V9.5.

Answer (score 1):

No, trust the documentation... :)

The [steps to enable JSON support in DB2](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/t0061301.html) are documented in the Knowledge Center. There is a dropdown menu to switch to the documentation for other DB2 versions. As you can see the description is only available for DB2 10.5 and 11.

An indicator that JSON is supported on your version is that you have a directory `sqllib/json` with either a `db2nosql.sh` or `db2nosql.bat` in the `sqllib/json/bin` directory.

Comment: yeah i too went through the document. So this means i need to install DB2 version 10.5 or higher in order to have those directory structure to enable DB2 json. Other that that there is no other way, am i right?